# Plotting signal label after crossover of previous week high

Tags: pine-script

This script is a setup to give accurate Go Long and Go Short signals. The Go Long signal is given when  the previous (short or neutral)position is stopped when the price crosses up the previous week high, and then the next day **or later** the price crosses, or is above the previous week high. For Go Short signal the inverse.
My problem is that the Go Long signal is only given if the price goes above the previous week high **the NEXT day**, not if it crosses later. I cannot figure it out, does anyone know how to approach this?

[image: Go long and Go short signals]

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at   https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=4
//By Juros

study(title="Universal weekly breakout", shorttitle="weekly breakout", overlay=true,   precision=8)
prevwkH = input(true, title="Show previous week high?")
prevwkL = input(true, title="show previous week low?")

//previous week high and low
prevWeekHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevWeekLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1], lookahead=true)

//previous Week high and low Plots
plot(prevwkH and prevWeekHigh ? prevWeekHigh : na, title="Prev Week High",    style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=1, color=color.fuchsia, transp=20)
plot(prevwkL and prevWeekLow ? prevWeekLow : na, title="Prev Week Low", style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=1, color=color.fuchsia, transp=20)

// stop location for short and long position (at crossover of previous week low or high)
Stopshort = crossover (high, prevWeekHigh)
Stoplong = crossunder (low, prevWeekLow)

Longposmemo = false
Longposmemo := Stopshort ? true : Stoplong ? false : Longposmemo[1]

Longcond = Stopshort and not Longposmemo[1]
color_1 = color.new(color.green, 70)


Shortposmemo = false
Shortposmemo := Stoplong ? true : Stopshort ? false : Shortposmemo[1]

Shortcond = Stoplong and not Shortposmemo[1]
color_2 = color.new(color.red, 70)
//bgcolor(Sellnow ? color_2 : na)

// alerts
//alertcondition(Stopshort, title="Buy now", message="buy now")
//alertcondition(Stoplong, title="Sell now", message="Sell now")


Golong = false 
Golong := high > prevWeekHigh and Longcond[1]

Goshort = false
Goshort := close < close[1] and Shortcond[1]

// plots : X where the position is stopped
plotchar (Longcond, char='X', location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow)
plotchar (Shortcond, char='X', location=location.belowbar, color=color.yellow)


plotshape (Golong ? high : na, style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.tiny, text = 'GOLONG', textcolor=color.black)
plotshape (Goshort ? low : na, style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.tiny, text ='GOSHORT', textcolor=color.black)

// alerts
alertcondition(Golong, title="Weakly breakout go long", message="WBO go long")
alertcondition(Goshort, title="weakly breakout go short", message="WBO go short")
```

Comment: So even when you're already long, you want long signals to continue firing on every bar where price is > previous weekly high?

Comment: No, when I'm long there is no need for another signal. The problem is when I'm long, and the long position is stopped (price < prev week low). Then the next day if the price does not cross under the prev week low there is no signal, that is good. But when the price crosses 2, 3 or more days later under the prev week low, I want the Goshort signal, and now it doesn't give that signal.